# program to count number of 0's and 1's

Tags: python

```
x = int(input('ENTER A NUMBER '))
count = 0
while x > 0:
    digit = x % 10
    if digit == 0 or digit == 1:
        count += 1
        x //= 10
print('THE NUMBER OF ONES OR ZEROES TOGETHER ARE: ', count)
```

If I run the above program with `x//10` inside the if loop, the output only comes true if the user enters number containing 0's and 1's, any other input and I do not get the output at all.

```
x = int(input('ENTER A NUMBER '))
count = 0
while x > 0:
    digit = x % 10
    if digit == 0 or digit == 1:
        count += 1
    x //= 10
print('THE NUMBER OF ONES OR ZEROES TOGETHER ARE: ', count)
```

This code works just fine. I am confused.

Comment: Because you get stuck in the infinite loop: if the digit is neither 0 nor 1 `x` is not modified meaning you do not get the next digit in the number (which `x//=10` provide).

Comment: Why even bother with arithmetic? Your input is already a string. The whole program can be  `x = input('ENTER A NUMBER ') ; print(x.count('0') + x.count('1'))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first snippet, the call:

```
x //= 10
```

is made *inside the if-statement*, so it is only executed when the current digit being evaluated is either a `0` or a `1`. This means that when it doesn't meet this condition, `x` is never modified, so the same test is run over and over again - never ending.

In the second snippet, the same call is made outside of the scope of the if-statement so regardless of what the current digit is, `x` is modified to have one less character and the *next* character is evaluated rather than the *same* one as was happening in the first snippet.